# h3 and anchor tag styling issues

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have the following html snippet which works correctly on my page:

```
<a href="url goes here" onclick="return ! window.open(this.href);"><h3>title goes here</h3></a>
```

using the following css

```
h3
{
    font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:75%; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-style:normal; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform:none; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    color:#2C6598;
}
```

However, this is not valid xhtml as the `<h3>` tag should not be within a `<a>` tag.

When I move the `<h3>` tags outside of the `<a>` tags, the css does not seem to work, i.e. it loses it's style for some reason.

For example:

```
<h3><a href="url goes here" onclick="return ! window.open(this.href);">title goes here</a></h3>
```

with:

```
h3
{
    font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:75%; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-style:normal; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform:none; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    color:#2C6598;
}
```

does not work the way it did with the `<h3>` tag within the `<a>` tags.

How can this be corrected?

Comment: change in css write `a>h3` and try

Comment: @diEcho - That does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: `a+h3` will work...please try

Comment: @diEcho both those suggestions are wrong. First you're trying for markup like `<a><h3></h3></a>` and the second is for `<a></a><h3></h3>`. The solution is to use either `h3>a` or `h3 a` depending on how specific you want to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to apply the style on `<a>` tag

try this

```
h3 a
{
    font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:75%; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-style:normal; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform:none; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    color:#2C6598;
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the styles for your anchor are taking precedence. You can simply change the stylesheet to

```
h3, h3 a /** Applies to both H3 and LINK inside H3 **/
{
    font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:75%; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-style:normal; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform:none; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    color:#2C6598;
}
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: That does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: @oshirowanen you'll need to put up some HTML on a fiddle or something and show what's wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I just simply made a new class with properties I wanted the final text to have, so it's something like that:

CSS: (it didn't work without "!important")

```
.myclass, .myclass a {
display: block !important;
font-size: 14px !important; 
font-weight: bold !important;
height: 32px !important;}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="myclass" "url goes here">title goes here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I encountered this problem.  You may have to cater for any pseudo classes which may be overriding your styles e.g. a:visited etc.  So what you would also need to to do is:

```
h3 a, a:visited 
{
   font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
   font-size:75%; 
   font-weight:bold; 
   font-style:normal; 
   text-decoration:none; 
   text-transform:none; 
   margin:0px; 
   padding:0px;
   color:#2C6598;
}
```